# Javascript with html form validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

i'm trying to validate a form using a simple javascript script however it is not working, can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? (sorry for my vague question)

**JS code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validation()
{                                 
    var fName=document.forms["teacherReg"]["firstname"].value;
    var lName=document.forms["teacherReg"]["lastname"].value;
    var uName=document.forms["teacherReg"]["username"].value;
    var pWord=document.forms["teacherReg"]["password"].value;
    var cPWord=document.forms["teacherReg"]["confirmpassword"].value;

    if (fName="" || lName="" || uName="" || pWord="")
    {
        alert("Not a valid entry");
        return false;
    }

}
</script>
```

**html form:**

```
<form name="teacherReg" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return validation();">
    1. First name:
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    2. Last name:<br/><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" /><br/><br/>                             
    3. Desired Username:
    <br/><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br/><br/>
    4. Desired Password:
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    5. Confirm Password:<br/><input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" /> <br/><br/>
    <center><input type="submit" value="Register" name="submitbutton" class="button" /></center>
</form>
```

I expect it to return false if any of the fields "fName, lName, uName, pWord" are blank, however it is always returning true

Comment: You shouldn't use UPPERCASE HTML (`<SCRIPT>`)

Comment: You should tell us what did you expect and what happened? why do you think it is not working? etc..

Comment: @Vadorequest `you shouldn't` html is not case sensetive

Comment: @user689 edited in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you confused [`=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) (assignment operator) operator with [`==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) (comparison operator):

```
if (fName = "" || lName = "" || uName = "" || pWord = "") {
```

It should be

```
if (fName == "" || lName == "" || uName == "" || pWord == "") {
```

#### Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/49xDH/

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
 if (fName=="" || lName=="" || uName=="" || pWord=="")
```

Answer (score 0):

`=` is assignment operator , where `==` is comparison operator. use `==` for comparing values.

Answer (score 0):

Use the comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`.

Comment: you shouldn't duplicate an already given answer without any added value

Comment: Yeah by the time i started typing ,an answer was posted .Its not my fault.Sorry bro..

Answer (score -3):

Please try to use the ID instead of the form object.

```
function validation(){
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: It also looks like your validation is wrong. `if (!fName || !lName || !uName || !pWord)`

Comment: @Vadorequest : This answer has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: It's better to use the ID than the document form. Clean. His code was badly indented, hard to understand and wasn't following stackoverflow presentation rules.